# Changing nested file structure by date to filename

Tags: bash

I have a nested set of directories that looks something like `2013/10/08/access.log.xz`, I can find all the log files I want with `find . -name \*access.log.xz`. I want to put them all in a single directory prefixed by date like `20131008_access.log.xz`. I don't even know where to start though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a recent bash or a shell with recursive globbing, you can do something like this:

```
shopt -s globstar
for logfile in **/*access.log.xz; do
  IFS=/ read year month day file <<< "$logfile"
  mv "$logfile" "${year}${month}${day}_${file}"
done
```

If you have an older bash, you can emulate the effect, but it's harder to read:

```
find . -name '*access.log.xz' -exec bash -c 'for logfile; do
    IFS=/ read dot year month day file <<< "$logfile"
    mv "$logfile" "${year}${month}${day}_${file}"
done' _ {} +
```